# Do i need to install my sql on my webserver or just my computer?

Tags: php, mysql, database, logging

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to create a login system with PhP and I figured out where to store usernames and passwords with it being hashed, but do I need to save them to a MySQL database on my server or just my computer that I have here. I would assume that I need to use it on my server but I don't know how.

Comment: This is a little to broad a question for SO - but look at [this article](https://code-boxx.com/password-encrypt-decrypt-php/) to get you started. They need to be stored but how is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use xamp if you are on Windows

2.Turn on Apache and MySql server

3.Go to localhost of Mysql and create a database